# How do I receive the user id from a session using next-auth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I've read the documentation on [session callbacks](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback) and tried implementing it by persisting a JWT token but still couldn't get it to work. The docs also says that when using NextAuth with a database (Firebase in my case, see adapter) it should:

> When using NextAuth.js with a database, the User object will be either a user object from the database (including the User ID) if the user has signed in before or a simpler prototype user object (i.e. name, email, image) for users who have not signed in before.

> When using NextAuth.js without a database, the user object will always be a prototype user object, with information extracted from the profile.

What am I missing here?

`[...nextauth].ts`

```js
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  }),
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account, profile }: any) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token and or the user id to the token right after signin
      if (account) {
        console.log("token", token);
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.id = profile.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }: any) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
      if (token) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
        session.user = {};
        session.user.id = token.id;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Console logging the session gives me:
[image: console log]

Answer (score 2):

your code looks fine, am working on a next project and I have almost the same, the only difference is that am using the `CredentialsProvider`.

```js
session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
session.user = {};
session.user.id = token.id;
```

should overwrite the session and it does for me.

the problem should be in the `if(token)` statement this somehow returning `false` try to `console.log` inside and see

Comment: That's weird; I have logged the user and that DOES have an id. But when I try to log the token in the session, there is none. Is this normal? I did fix my problem now, by returning  `if (user) {
        session.user = {};
        session.user.id = user.id;}`

Comment: yeah I was sure that there was no token

Comment: Do you see why that is?

Comment: I don't know maybe because when using database the token object cannot be accessible from the session callback.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add the user id to the the session you need to take it from the `token.sub`.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple approach I found after some frustrating attempts.

```
callbacks: {
 async session({ session, user, token }) {
  return {
   ...session,
   user,
   token
  }
 }
}
```

**EDIT:**
So my initial problem was that I could retrieve the usedId to run validation or authentication in my application but later I found out there was something missing. Here is the revised code:

```
import { db } from '@/app/_lib/prisma'
// import { generateRandomBankAccount } from '@/app/_utils/formatters'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter'
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import { Adapter } from 'next-auth/adapters'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db) as Adapter,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = token.access_token
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        session.user.id = user.id
        token
        user
      }

      return session
    },
  },
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).